# Usage of BehindSubString in nolinkurl (hyperref)

Tags: hyperref, strings

I often use QR codes in my teaching material to provide links to videos or GeoGebra stuff. In order to give an easier non-smartphone (non-tablet) access to these resources, I would like to print the URL underneath the code.

As the codes are printed as margin notes, there is not much space available. I therefore would want to remove the `http://` part. However `\BehindSubString` and `\nolinkurl` do not like each other:

```
\documentclass{minimal} 

\usepackage{substr}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\def\URL{http://tex.stackexchange.com}

\nolinkurl{\URL}

\nolinkurl{\BehindSubString{http://}{\URL}}

\end{document}
```

Last line is causing a lot of errors. How can I use the return value of `\BehindSubstring` in `\nolinkurl`? Or is there another easy way of stripping the protocol prefix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`\BehindSubString` is not expandable. If your macros for URLs always have the protocol (and contain no special character), you can do it by

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\stripprot[1]{\expandafter\strip@prot#1\strip@prot}
\def\strip@prot #1://#2\strip@prot{#2}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\def\URL{http://tex.stackexchange.com}

\nolinkurl{\URL}

\nolinkurl{\stripprot{\URL}}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. An amazing simplicity -- if one knows that trick, of course. I use it in a `\IfSubStringInString` construction, so it works whether or not the protocol is there. Special chars are not a problem either, I mainly have "standard" short URLs.